# Help identifying frame number

Tags: security, theft

On my new bike I can see two numbers stamped into the frame - one seven digits long and one eight digits long. There's also a serial number on a tag.

[image]
[image]

I'm attempting to register the Bike with the UK [BikeRegister](https://www.bikeregister.com/) scheme, which asks for the frame number.

Which number is the right one to use?

Comment: thanks, I was facing the same problem and this post was helpful. Another related question - did you use UV covert marking from bikeregister?

Comment: I decided that I didn't think it was worth it - but I have got bike insurance that covers theft of the bike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a Triban road bike from Decathlon.

The Serial Number is the one labelled Serial Number in the bottom right corner of the sticker.  This will be encoded in that barcode above.  This number refers to the entire bike once assembled, and this will be the one used on warranty documents.

The one stamped on the frame will be a frame serial number, used to help identify the frame as it moves through to assembly.  It will be a sub-assembly of the whole bike, along with any other component serial numbers.

For your purposes

- Brand: Triban
- Model: DC120 Disk
- Size: Large
- Colour: Blue
- Supplier: Decathlon
- Serial Number: 560243      (Because its clearly labelled as the serial number)

Other info:

- Frame Numbers: 1982118 and 10437355    (Check these - could be reading it wrong)
- Additional Numbers: 010360840986423921 and 2733283

I would include every number that is on the bike in your paperwork somewhere.  Additional fields, or even a comment field can be searched by computers, so someday if there's a need, your bike is a little more likely to match.

**Other suggestions**

I'd also check the saddle and bars and stem for any kind of serial number, unlikely on a £399 bike, but worth exploring.  Perhaps even engrave your name/number in an inconspicuous place.

If the bike was stolen, an astute thief could "accidentally" erase the sticker with some solvents, or scratch it up so that the serial number is illegible and blame an "accident putting it on the roofrack of a car" or something plausible.

So you can engrave or stamp the serial number from the sticker directly onto the frame. Its an aluminium frame so you'd want to be careful choosing a location to avoid stress risers.

On the bottom of the seat post, down inside the frame could be an excellent spot.  As could engraving an identifier onto your pedals.

That you have a photo of your bike's serial right now might be another way to prove ownership in the future, so don't delete it.