# GT Dyno BMX bike Somebody please tell me what year amd model it is

Tags: bmx

I have a chrome Dyno in my garage and am wondering if anyone can help me identify the year and what kind of Dyno specifically it is. The serial number reads KG1JO6869. From the things I've read on the internet I was thinking it was from Taiwan and maybe a 91 but not completely sure.  Also another thing is what does the number 1 on the serial number indicate? What I've read so far there is only sequence of 8, 4 letter followed my 4 numbers however with the 1 in the number it makes 9. Also the thing is if you look at the number a certain way the one doesn't look nearly as stamped as the rest. Please can anyone shed some light.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help identifying frame number](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/help-identifying-frame-number)

Comment: No I'm specifically looking how to read and identify GT Dyno because I can't really be certain myself I'm not experienced enough for that yet

Comment: I brought together all of the scattered info on the Internet [in my answer here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/82879/i-have-a-gt-dyno-serial-number-wyc8i00217-who-can-help-me-get-the-year-and-model). Bottom line is GT serial numbers are not systematic enough to decipher with certainty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a Gt dyno serial number WYC8I00217 who can help me get the year and model](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/82879/i-have-a-gt-dyno-serial-number-wyc8i00217-who-can-help-me-get-the-year-and-model)